# Where PWA store photos?

Tags: android, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I've the PWA app, launched on Android device. The app allow to take pictures and upload them to server.

I wonder, **where PWA app store this photos?** In the browser cache or somewhere in android app directory?

Answer (score 1):

PWA app can only store the pages/files in cache and it cannot access android directory. So, PWA can store images in cache if it is offline and sync the files to server then when it is offline.

Comment: Thanks for response! Do you have any source of this informations? Any documentation or articles to get some more details?